# Is it possible to test arguments in mocked constructor with mockk?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

##### Purpose

I want to test the result of a function of a class. And it returns an instance of an Android class, which should be mocked in a unit test since it seems to be stubbed in any unit test.

##### Example code

Here's a minimized example code of the simulated android class, `AndroidData`, and the class to be tested, `MyHelper`.

```
/**
 * Should be mocked in a unit test.
 */
class AndroidData(val value: Float)

/**
 * Target class to be tested.
 */
class MyHelper() {
    fun createData(flag: Boolean): AndroidData {
        // simplified logic
        return if (flag) AndroidData(20f) else AndroidData(10f)
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is something like this(**note that this is incorrect code**):

```
class MyHelperTest : TestCase() {
    @Test
    fun testCreateData() {
        mockkConstructor(AndroidData::class)
        val valueSlot = slot<Float>()
        every { constructedWith<AndroidData>(capture(valueSlot)) }  // Type mismatch in IDE
        val helper = MyHelper()
        
        val returnedData = helper.createData(true)
        assertTrue(returnedData.value >= 15f)
    }
}
```

I want to test that returned `AndroidData` instance has a correct `value`, or matches some conditions. I cannot find any tutorial about this case or any correct way to implement it.

##### What I tried

These 2 test cases would both fail.

```
    @Test
    fun testCreateData1() {
        mockkConstructor(AndroidData::class)

        val helper = mockk<MyHelper>(relaxed = true)
        val createdData = helper.createData(true)

        println("createdData=$createdData")  // AndroidData(child of #1#2)
        println("createdData.value=${createdData.value}")  // 0.0

        // test if the argument in AndroidData's constructor was larger than 15
        assertTrue(createdData.value >= 15f)  // assertion failed
    }

    @Test
    fun testCreateData2() {
        mockkConstructor(AndroidData::class)
        // raise error: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock
        every {
            constructedWith<AndroidData>(LargerThan15Matcher())
        }

        val helper = mockk<MyHelper>(relaxed = true)
        val createdData = helper.createData(true)

        println("createdData=$createdData")  // AndroidData(child of #1#2)
        println("createdData.value=${createdData.value}")  // 0.0

        // test if the argument in AndroidData's constructor was larger than 15
        assertTrue(createdData.value >= 15f)
    }
```

The testing idea was pretty easy and intuitive for Python unittest in my experience. Yet it seems impossible in Java or Android? I haven't tried the `mockito` and `roboletric` library because I was told that `mockk` provides support on Android projects. Or I just haven't found the correct way to do this, or the whole testing idea is completely wrong? Please end my days of searching and struggle.

#### Update 0815

With @Karsten Gabriel 's suggestion, I made a bit of mod on the `testCreateData2()` test case, but still it doesn't work. The `createdData` seems not really an `AndroidData` instance and has `value` 0.0.

```
    @Test
    fun testCreateData2() {
        mockkConstructor(AndroidData::class)
        // Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock
        every {
            constructedWith<AndroidData>(LargerThan15Matcher()).value
        } returns 1f

        val helper = mockk<MyHelper>(relaxed = true)
        val createdData = helper.createData(true)

        println("createdData=$createdData")  // AndroidData(child of #1#2)
        println("createdData.value=${createdData.value}")  // 0.0

        // test if the argument in AndroidData's constructor was larger than 15
        assertTrue(createdData.value >= 15f)
    }
```

BTW, the `LargerThan15Matcher`:

```
class LargerThan15Matcher : Matcher<Float> {
    override fun match(arg: Float?): Boolean {
        return if (arg == null) false else arg >= 15f
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but I can try to help you with what I think I understand.

Let's start with your test-case `testCreateData1`:

- A relaxed mock in MockK tries to return a "simple value" (mostly "default" values or null if possible) for each function call of the mock.
- Therefore, your relaxed mock of `MyHelper` returns `AndroidData(0.0)` which does not satisfy your assertion.

Regarding test-case `testCreateData2`:

- `every { ... }` alone is not a proper expression, but it is intended to specify what should happen on every `...`. For instance, if you have a mock `m` with a function `f` you could write something like the following:

```kotlin
every { m.f() } returns 42
every { m.f() } answers { callOriginal() }
```

- In pretty much the same way, `constructedWith<AndroidData>(LargerThan15Matcher())` is not a proper expression, because it is intended to specify what should happen with an AndroidData constructed with an argument matched by the `LargerThan15Matcher`. For instance, if you want to say that the `value` of such an object should always return 1 you could write

```kotlin
 every { constructedWith<AndroidData>(LargerThan15Matcher()).value } returns 1f
```

#### Update 0815

Your updated test does not work due to an unfortunate combination of mocking:

- You mock each constructed element of `AndroidData`.
- But at the same time you also have a (relaxed) mock of `MyHelper` which does not call the constructor of `AndroidData`, but instead it gives you some mock of `AndroidData`.

There are (at least) two possibilities to solve this:

1. You do not mock `MyHelper` but only constructed values of `AndroidData`:

```kotlin
mockkConstructor(AndroidData::class)
every {
    constructedWith<AndroidData>(LargerThan15Matcher()).value
} returns 20f

val helper = MyHelper()
val createdData = helper.createData(true)

assertTrue(createdData.value >= 15f)
```

2. You mock `MyHelper` and you explicitly define how your mock should work:

```kotlin
val helper = mockk<MyHelper> {
    every { createData(true) } returns AndroidData(20f)
}

val createdData = helper.createData(true)

// test if the argument in AndroidData's constructor was larger than 15
assertTrue(createdData.value >= 15f)
```

or

```kotlin
val helper = mockk<MyHelper> {
    every { createData(true) } returns mockk {
        every { value } returns 20f
    }
}

val createdData = helper.createData(true)

assertTrue(createdData.value >= 15f)
```

Comment: Hi @Karsten, thanks for the response. I just want to test that the returned `AndroidData` instance has the correct `value` yet cannot find the right way.

Comment: As the `testCreateData2()`, still it can't work with your suggestion. I'll update the original post.

Comment: @JoyWen I extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think the first approach in your 0815 update would partially satisfy my purpose. IMHO it's an alternative to test the logic in `createData()` and the `AndroidData` object it returned.

Seems it's impossible to directly "capture" the `value` in the returned `AndroidData` object, for `mockk` framework. While it should be easy in my previous experience (with `Python unittest`).

@Karsten Truly thanks for your help :)